# json_decode($string, true) returns a string of 'Array' instead of the Array itself

Tags: php, json, base64, mcrypt

I believe the problem is that I am `base64_encoding` the json string and when I `base64_decode` the string and run `json_decode($string, true)` for some reason it just returns the string of 'Array'.

Here is where I pass the json to be encoded:

```
$data = '[{"id":"1","name":"Dave","email":"dave@test.com","password":"1610838743cc90e3e4fdda748282d9b8","isAdmin":"true","timeStamp":"2012-09-18 20:37:38"}]';

Session::set('user', $data, true);
```

Here is my base64 encode/decode code:

```
public static function set($key, $value, $encrypt = false) {
    if ($encrypt == false) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $_SESSION[$key] = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(SALT1), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(SALT2))));
    }
}

public static function get($key, $decrypt = false) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        if ($decrypt == false) {
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        } else {
            return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(SALT1), base64_decode($_SESSION[$key]), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(SALT2))), "\0");
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is where I make the call to decode the value:

```
$user = Session::get('user', true);

echo json_decode($user, true);
```

And my result is:

```
Array
```

I have looked into the different mcrypt modes, but was unsuccessful in finding a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try print_r (json_decode($user, true)); ?

Comment: `json_encode()` or `json_decode` ? According to the PHP documentation [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) expects an `int` as a second parameter, whereas [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) expects a `bool` as a second param.

Comment: echo statement doesn't print your array. use print_r to check your array

Comment: @Havelock did you read the question ? The OP uses `json_decode` with a `bool` as the second param ....

Comment: wow my bad, that's how you know its 2:00 am... thanks GBD! ;P

Comment: @ManseUK check the post edit history ;-)

Comment: Ya sorry Havelock, another 2:00 am typo :)

Comment: @DaveCottrell I thought it might be, just wanted to make sure ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `echo` just outputs an string. you will have to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to view the array.

```
print_r(json_decode($user, true));
```

or use

```
var_dump(json_decode($user, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

print_r(json_decode($user, true));